# Resulting array from PapaParse not filling out ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv, papaparse

I am trying to upload a csv and then run it thru PapaParse into a JSON. After PapaParse i store it as $scope.dataTable and it logs to the console properly but it doesnt populate my ng-repeat and i cant figure out why.

```
var app = angular.module('rainApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.dataTable = [];

    $scope.csv = document.getElementById("file-input");

    function buildTable(a) {
        $scope.dataTable = a;
        console.log($scope.dataTable);
    }

    function dataToJson(data, callback) {
        Papa.parse(data, {
            header: false,
            complete: function(results) {
                callback(results.data);
            }
        });
    }

    $scope.csv.addEventListener("change", function() {
        data = this.files[0];
        dataToJson(data, buildTable);
    });
});
```

and HTML (i load the angular scripts above)

```
  <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <input id="file-input" type="file" accept=".csv" />
<div ng-repeat="item in dataTable">
  <h1>{{item}}</h1>
</div>

  </div>
```

contents of JSON from console.log

```
[
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-01",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.8"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-02",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.3"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-03",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-04",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-05",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-06",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-07",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-08",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-09",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-10",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-11",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-12",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-13",
    "Precip. (mm)": "2.3"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-14",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-15",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-16",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Township": "T024R01W5",
    "Date": "1955-01-17",
    "Precip. (mm)": "0.8"
  },
  {
    "Township": ""
  }
]
```

Comment: Is json format correct? It must be json array. Can you paste here what shown when you console.log datatable

Comment: Papaparse doesn't deal with JSON, and neither does your code - what you've got there is a javascript array - which is fine, because the line `$scope.dataTable = a;` expects an array, not a JSON **string** ... so, to re-iterate, this question has **nothing** to do with JSON in any way

Comment: according to PapaParse documentation it does http://papaparse.com/docs#csv-to-json

That being said, if the results.data coming from PapaParse is just an array I think I can figure out how to make it JSON.

Comment: you don't want JSON at all in your code - and reading that papparse documentation about converting JSON to CSV, `the input is an array of arrays or an array of objects` ... neither of which are JSON - the author of PapaParse is suffering a common delusion about what JSON is. I use PapaParse extensively, and have **never** done any JSON parse or stringify to deal with the results / input data for papaparse functions

Comment: i will remove the tag, appreciate the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After *$scope.dataTable = a;*
Try to add this new Line:

*$scope.$apply();*

Comment: Thanks that worked great... now i just need to dive in to find out why :)

Comment: You know, when you bind something on your view, angular add a watcher. when you have async tasks, you have to notify the watchers. For example in the implementation of $http, $timeout..etc there is a $scope.$apply() at the end. It means that angular propage at event from root scope to all the child scope to sync data between view and model (update all the watchers). And because using papa u are using async out of the framework, you have to explicitly refresh watchers.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense then, i much appreciate the response! Thanks